# Pickles: Why are they called that?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm surprised this is such a hard answer for me to find.

It's such a strange name.  Why are pickles called pickles?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pickle_(Python)

I understand what "pickling" means with respect to vegetables and I understand that the python concept is analogous.  But, why choose "pickle" instead of "serialization"?  Is it an inside joke?  Is there a history about it?

Comment: "Pickling" is process which enables storage and preservation.

Comment: "Pickle" is "Pickle" because "Python" is "Python".

Comment: And for the same reason that "bug" is called "bug"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the verb [*to pickle*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pickle):

> vegetables, such as cauliflowers, onions, etc, preserved in vinegar, brine, etc

It is Python objects, preserved for later use. The name was [taken from the Modula-3 concept](http://legacy.python.org/workshops/1994-11/FlattenPython.html), a language that inspired many Python features. Also see the [Module-3 Pickle documentation](https://modula3.elegosoft.com/cm3/doc/help/gen_html/libm3/src/pickle/ver1/Pickle.i3.html).

I suspect Guido picked the name because:

- it is better than the first name he thought of (*flatten*, see [this old usenet post announcing it](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/2YDZwyojUPE/UqWK1JpPTEsJ))
- funny names are better than drab ones, in tradition with the Monty Python background of the language
- there is a nice alliteration going on there with the P's (**P**ython **P**ickles)
- you put pickles (in jars) on a [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), a module added to the library [in the same commit](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/4574ed657cc9).

If you ever get hold of [Guido's time machine](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/Guido.html) you could travel back to [November 1994](http://legacy.python.org/workshops/1994-11/agenda.html) and ask him yourself why he picked that specific name. I do notice that Ken Mannheimer already uses the term *pickled objects* a mere [10 days after the announcement of `flatten`](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.python/2YDZwyojUPE/dEPHV25ufMwJ) as part of the follow-up discussion, probably [referencing to the Modula-3 inspiration for the concept](http://legacy.python.org/workshops/1994-11/persistency.html), and the name must've stuck.