# Is there any difference between Pickling and Serialization?

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

I have came across these two terms so often while reading about python objects. However, there is a confusion between pickling and serialization since at one place I read

> The pickle module implements an algorithm for turning an arbitrary
>   Python object into a series of bytes. This process is also called
>   **serializing**” the object.

If serializing and pickling is same process, why use different terms for them?

Comment: Pickling is *one form* of serialising. Serialisation in a generic term, also applicable to JSON, XML, and other formats.

Comment: Note *"...implements **an** algorithm for..."*, (i.e. not **the** algorithm) implying that there are other serialisation algorithms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are misreading the article. Pickling and serialisation are not synonymous, nor does the text claim them to be.

Paraphrasing slighly, the text *says* this:

> This module implements an **algorithm** for turning an object into a series of bytes. **This process** is also called *serializing* the object.

I removed the module name, `pickle`, deliberately. The module implements a process, an algorithm, and that process is commonly known as *serialisation*.

There are other implementations of that process. You could use JSON or XML to serialise data to text. There is also the [`marshal` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/marshal.html). Other languages have other serialization formats; the [R language has one](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/serialize.html), so [does Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Etc.

See the [WikiPedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization):

> In computer science, in the context of data storage, **serialization** is the process of translating data structures or object state into a format that can be stored (for example, in a file or memory buffer, or transmitted across a network connection link) and reconstructed later in the same or another computer environment.

Python picked the name `pickle` because it modelled the process on how this was handled in [Modula-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modula-3), where it was also called pickling. See [Pickles: Why are they called that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324986/pickles-why-are-they-called-that)

Answer (score 1):

in python `pickle` refers to a module that provides (a specific) serialization of python objects.

serialization itself is a more general term. python objects can also be serialized into json for example.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization